# Whether Windows 8.1 apps will work in Windows 8 PC?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

I am developing an application in Windows 8.1 Preview release using VS 2013. When i deploy the App package in the Windows 8 PC, it did not run. I have a small question that whether Windows 8.1 developed apps will run in Windows 8 PC. If it needs to run, any other specification suppose to be provided for the apps or PC ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you target 8.1 then the app will not run in windows 8. That is because the api of 8.1 is extended and the new features do not exist in windows 8. If you develop in windows 8.1 and you target windows 8. Then the apps will just work out of the box.

For example, windows 8.1 supports new controls. If you target 8.1 you can use those controls, but when you use windows 8, those controls do not exist and thus the application cant run.

Comment: Just wanted to be clear on the term "targeting 8.1" here. I created a Windows Store app with Visual Studio 2013 (Preview) supporting Framework 4.5.1. In Visual Studio 2013 Solution Explorer, the app is displayed as "TestApp1 (Windows 8.1)". Now, is there a way to make this app run in Windows 8.0?

Comment: I have no windows 8.1 machine at hand to test this. But I presume you can edit it in the project settings.

Comment: If that is not possible you should recreate your project as a Windows 8 app. You can easily migrate from 8 to 8.1 by rightclicking your windows 8 project and click on migrate to 8.1

Comment: @SynerCoder please provide any source link as guidenece.

Comment: @kumar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182410.aspx anything here that is described can not be used in 8.0 because those only exist in 8.1